# Azure Release pipeline does not clean the Package folder of the agent

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have the following release pipeline for an asp.net 6 app which publishes the site to an IIS server

```
trigger:
- none

variables:
    IISWebsiteName: 'MyAspNetApp'

resources:
 pipelines:
     - pipeline: 'buildPipeline'
       project: 'My Asp Net App'
       source: 'Build pipeline'
       branch: 'main'
       

stages:
 - stage: 'DeployeWebSite'
   displayName: 'Deploy website'
   pool:
     vmImage: windows-latest
    
   jobs:
   - deployment: DeployWebsite
     displayName: 'Deploy website'
     environment: 'dev-web01.VMI835964'
     strategy:
      runOnce:
          deploy:
           steps:
               - checkout: none

               - download: 'buildPipeline'
                 name: 'DownloadBuildArtifacts'           
                 displayName: 'Download build artifacts'
                 artifact: 'My Asp Net App'
              
               - task: IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0
                 name: 'StopIIS'
                 displayName: 'Stop IIS website - ${{ variables.IISWebsiteName }}'
                 inputs:
                    IISDeploymentType: 'IISWebsite'
                    ActionIISWebsite: 'StopWebsite'
                    StartStopWebsiteName: '${{ variables.IISWebsiteName }}'         
                  
               - script: echo '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\buildPipeline\My Asp Net App'
                            
               - task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
                 name: 'DeployIIS'
                 displayName: 'Deploy IIS website - ${{ variables.IISWebsiteName }}'         
                 inputs:
                    WebSiteName: '${{ variables.IISWebsiteName }}'             
                    Package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\buildPipeline\My Asp Net App'
                    TakeAppOfflineFlag: true
            
               - task: IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0
                 name: 'StartIIS'
                 displayName: 'Start IIS website - ${{ variables.IISWebsiteName }}'               
                 inputs:
                    IISDeploymentType: 'IISWebsite'
                    ActionIISWebsite: 'StartWebsite'
                    StartStopWebsiteName: '${{ variables.IISWebsiteName }}'
```

Problem is that as soon as it the pipeline runs it does not clear the agent folder where temporarily uploads file (to replace IIS Website). Is there any way to force it to clean that folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this option: [Clean the local repo on the agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/pipeline-options-for-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#clean-the-local-repo-on-the-agent)

For release, check deployment section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-deployment?view=azure-pipelines

[image]

Comment: This cleans the sources and output directory. I'm running a release pipeline.

Comment: @pantonis check my updates